# How to use Behat in Cake Php?

Tags: testing, cakephp, bdd, behat

I have this feature

Feature: User accesses Appointments Dashboard

```
Scenario:
Given I am on "User Dashboard Page"
And I should see "APPOINTMENTS"
And I should see "PRE-ENROLMENTS"
When I press "APPOINTMENTS"
Then I am on "Appointments Dashboard"
And I should see "Booking Reference"
And I should see "Book Another Appointment"
```

And I have these steps

--- FeatureContext has missing steps. Define them with these snippets:

```
/**
 * @Given I am on :arg1
 */
public function iAmOn($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}

/**
 * @Given I should see :arg1
 */
public function iShouldSee($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}

/**
 * @When I press :arg1
 */
public function iPress($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

How do I complete the steps and run it with Behat in Cake Php ?
So, that my tests pass ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to yuor CakePHP internals, then you'll probably want to have an instance of CakePHP application in your Context (e.g.
`App\Application` or `Cake\Http\Server`, look at your [index.php](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/5.0/webroot/index.php) on it's done). Then, hopefully you'll be able to access all of the usual application internals via default [Service Container](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/dependency-injection.html) of CakePHP.